# DynamoDB .NET SDK Get only Specific Properties

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an application that I'm trying to store data in Amazon DynamoDB and I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure the tables.  A quick description of the app:

It needs to be able to load a large number of elements from the DB based on a search of a small number of properties and display those limited properties to the user.  Then the user can browse and select a few elements that they want to look closer at and it needs to show the rest of the properties for those items.

My thought is that basically for speed and memory purposes it needs to load a 'summarized' version of the objects for the initial step, then load the full object when the user asks to look into something fully.  I can do this easily (and have done so) in my c# code.  However here is what I'm wondering:

If I have a c# object and I use the Dynamo Object persistence SDK to relate say 5 properties to a Dynamo table that has say 30 properties; will the SDK request only the properties that are on the object?  Or will it request all of them and then throw out the 25 that aren't related to the object?

If it only takes the needed properties then I think I can store everything in one table and relate both the summarized objects and the full objects to the same table and just pull the properties needed.  If it takes everything then I'm worried it will create a lot of throughput that I don't need 75% of, plus slowing down the transfer due to the extra data.  If that's the case I think it may be worth creating a GSI that just has the summarized properties...

Anyway sorry for the long description, any input from those more familiar with DynamoDB than I am would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question, but have you read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)?. Basically, on all read operations, you can provide a `ProjectionExpression` parameter in which you specificy exactly which attributes / properties you want to fetch from the table.

Comment: I have read it, and I'm aware that Dynamo can do that. My question is more specific to the .NET SDK for object persistence.  Basically I can map a c# class to a Dynamo table and the SDK will take care of I/O operations from the database.  I can tell Amazon's SDK to go get objects of type 'X' and it returns me my own object type based on the DB data.  What I'm wondering is if the DB has more properties than the object if it's smart enough to use this system to avoid a lot of unnecessary overhead...